# java-how to get number class files executed by particuler test class from sonar qube data base

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

hi guys how can i get information like how many number of class files which will be executed from particular test class from sonarqube database,my sonarqube database is resided in MySQL db i am not finding any answers can guys help to this problem

Comment: Your question is really unclear...

Comment: actually my requirement is to get name of class files which are mapped to particuler test class from sonar qube database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: it is not recommended to access SonarQube DB to get information, so forget about directly manipulating SQ's database.

A longer answer might be: have a look at SonarQube's webservice API, especially these ones :

http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/tests/list 
http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/tests/covered_files

The first one should allow you to retrieve all test `id` then you can pass the ID you're looking for to the second webservice then check the size of the `files` array... but I don't think that this will be easy as it isn't straightforward to get the `testFileId` you need to feed the first webservice (you can't pass a file's key as far as I know.)

Comment: ya i tried but how to get the testFileId i tried many queries in sonar qube db but iam not able to get testFileId

Comment: actually my requirement is to get name of class files which are mapped to particuler test class from sonar qube database